# MySQL Find laptops with a speed slower than that of any pc

Tags: mysql

Relations:

```
Product(maker, model, type) 

Laptop(Model, price, speed, ram, hd, screen) 

PC(model, price, speed, ram, hd) 

Printer(model,price, color, price)
```

I am trying to find the laptops that have a speed slower than that of any pc.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT model FROM laptop WHERE laptop.speed < 
(SELECT speed FROM pc WHERE pc.speed < all);
```

I am trying to get the slowest speed in the pc relation and compare that speed to the speeds of the laptops. Which I figure would give me the relation I am looking for. I just keep getting a syntax error.

Comment: From my understanding, it means all elements kind of like *.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT model FROM laptop WHERE laptop.speed < (SELECT MIN(speed) FROM pc)
```

Learn more about the MIN() function [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

`MIN` is what you want:

```
SELECT model FROM laptop WHERE laptop.speed < 
(SELECT MIN(speed) FROM pc);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't study MAX,MIN etc yet then probably you want this

```
SELECT model
FROM Laptop
WHERE speed < ALL 
  (SELECT speed FROM PC);
```